# How to stop UITableView from loading until data has been fetched?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I understand that `UITableView` will call `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method to get each of the cells for the table view. Say I have my data source is fetched over the internet and I have to account for latency. What will be the best way of "stopping" this method from being called? Should it block on a boolean flag in the application? Should I just call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` again from within my application?

I am uncertain as to when the function gets called, ie, how often the `UITableView` "refreshes" itself. Any explanations will be helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you don't have data, or you don't have the data for additional cells, then `cellForRowAtIndex:` will not be called as long as you don't tell the UTableView that you have rowCounts or new rowCounts.  That value is being set in `numberOfRowsInSection:`.

In other words, don't report any new cells in `numberOfRowsInSection:`, until you actually have that data in hand, and then `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` won't be called prematurely.

When you do get the additional row data, then call `reloadData` to get the UITableView to ask for the number of rows and then call `cellForRowAtIndex:`.

Comment: thanks for this answer. how would you set numeberOfRowsInSection later? when reloadData is called, will cellForRowAtIndex or numberOfRowsInSection be called automatically?

Comment: Yes, when you call reloadData, many of these calls will be made automatically.

Comment: Another way to do this is to have your `UITableViews.dataSource` property be set to nil until you're ready to load it. Then you set it and call `reloadData`. This works great if you just need to wait for one request to finish for the initial table load.

Answer (score 6):

If you've set `UITableView` datasource and delegate from IB then it will at least go for  `numberOfRowsInSection` method when you push to the view, however if you're showing data from an `NSArray`, it'll return  count ZERO if array is still empty, so table won't go for other methods to call.

In practice, I'm pulling data from web service to feed the table, so I am not setting up the datasource and delegate from IB instead once I get the data and status `OK` response I'd set the `tableview.datasource = self` and `tableview.delegate = self` and then call `reloadData` method to update table. This ensures that it won't go for `numberOfRowsInSection` method as you don't need to call it up without having the data.

Comment: and yes, when you set `tableview.datasource = self` and `tableview.delegate = self` at least for that time you don't need to call `reloadData`.

Comment: How to prevent the tableview from reloading data upon setting the datasource? I want it to reload manually, as I do animation after setting the datasource.

Comment: Thanks bro, u saved my time :)

Comment: Glad my old answer helped you, you can also try [this](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet) in your project. @SamarthKejriwal

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is call reloadData on your table view when your data is done being fetched.  That will force the table view to call it's delegate methods again for display.  Those methods are called whenever the table view needs to re-display, so either when it comes into view, scrolling occurs, or you manually call reloadData.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `[tableView reloadData]`, the framework automatically invokes all the data source methods again for the table view cells that are visible currently (not for all the cells of the tableview). So the best approach would be to invoke reloadData every time you get data from the internet.